# Can't get navigation width to work properly

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm still sort of in the beginning stages of learning HTML & CSS so forgive me if this is an easy fix, but I haven't seen anything to answer this question.
So I'm trying to get equally sized navigation links- I've only got 4 links and setting the width to 25% doesn't seem to be working. I've messed with everything from blocking to changing the font size and no matter what I do, the navigation overflows instead of staying on one line like so:

[image: screenshot of navigation]

It looks like this in both Chrome and Firefox, I haven't bothered testing other browsers yet. Here's my code:

```
<div class="nav">
        <div class="navbar">
        <a class="active" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        <a href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> Portfolio</a>
        <a href="about.html"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> About</a>
        <a href="contact.html"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
    .nav {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
  .navbar a {
    font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 25%;
  }
  
  .navbar a:hover {
    color: #fb4c1f;
  }
  
  .navbar a.active {
    background-color: #fb4c1f;
    color: white;
  }
  

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .navbar a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

I'm pretty sure my nav div is redundant as well but I'm not totally focused on that at the moment. Right now I just want to figure out these links!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bit of padding that widens the item by 20px. You can account for this by using `calc(25% - 20px)` like so:

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #fb4c1f;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #fb4c1f;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
    <a href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> Portfolio</a>
    <a href="about.html"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> About</a>
    <a href="contact.html"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you, such an easy fix! I had a feeling it had something to do with the padding but wasn't 100% sure nor was I sure how to fix it. You're a lifesaver!